# Get the current value of a Slider via Javascript and store it in a variable

Tags: javascript, slider, getelementbyid

I basically want to make a webpage which changes the background color with the speed from a range slider.
Here is my coode:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<title>Color Change</title>
</head>
<body id="colo">
<input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="10000" step="1.0" value="1000" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" >
<output id="output">1000</output>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #DBF9FC;
}
```

JS:

```
let i = 0;
function colorchange() {
    let doc = document.getElementById("colo");
    let color = ["yellow", "blue", "red", "green", "orange","pink","lightblue","purple"];
    doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
    i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}

intervall=1000;
setInterval(colorchange,intervall);
```

The variable intervall should take the value from the slider range but i don't get any solution that works. I would be glad if someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you can just use `document.getElementById(“speed”).value`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this allready but get the error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Make sure your not using the function on the top level (not inside any functions), otherwise it will try and find it immediately and it won’t find anything because the DOM hasn’t loaded by then. It may help to have a ‘submit’ button that sets the variable and calls the function when you click it.